# Iterating through list with foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach

When trying to loop through a list as below, how would I implement a `foreach` loop?

```
ProductCollection myCollection = new ProductCollection
{
   Products = new List<Product>
   {
      new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M},
      new Product { Name = "Lifejacket", Price = 48.95M },
      new Product { Name = "Soccer ball", Price = 19.60M },
      new Product { Name = "Corner flag", Price = 34.95M }
   }
};
```

Comment: What is ProductCollection? Show all relevant code! How does Products property look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show us all relevant code if you want us to help you.

Anyway, if ProductCollection is like:

```
 public class ProductCollection 
 {
      public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
 }
```

then fill it like:

```
 ProductCollection myCollection = new ProductCollection
    {
        Products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M},
            new Product { Name = "Lifejacket", Price = 48.95M },
            new Product { Name = "Soccer ball", Price = 19.60M },
            new Product { Name = "Corner flag", Price = 34.95M }
        }
    };
```

and iterate like:

```
 foreach (var product in myCollection.Products) 
 {
      var name = product.Name;
      // etc...
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(var product in myCollection.Products)
{
    // Do something with product
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var item in myCollection.Products) 
{
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: tried this but Products brings up error ' the name Products does not exist in the current context

Comment: Update your question with `ProductCollection` class structure, if it does not work.

Comment: @davidjones, You need to put the things you've tried in the question, as well as put the errors you've gotten. Also, post all relevant code (e.g. ProductCollection).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a collection containing a collection. In this case you could use a nested foreach to iterate, but if you just want the products, it is not too pretty.

Instead, you could use the LINQ `SelectMany` extension method to flatten the collection:

```
foreach(var product in myCollection.SelectMany(col => col.Products))
    ; // work on product
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
 foreach(Product product in myCollection.Products)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.-

```
foreach (var product in myCollection.Products) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked i could then do: 
                Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}, Price: {1:c}",product.Name, product.Price);